# Xamarin forms shell: how to add header toolbar logo?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-shell

In a "xamarin forms shell" application, how do I add a logo image in the center of the header toolbar?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="mytoolbaritem.png"
             Order="Primary"
             Priority="0"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.HomePage" BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        ...
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: can u try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64798384/how-could-i-change-the-navigastions-page-arrow-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [Display views in the navigation bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar) by customize `Shell.TitleView` inside `ContentPage`:

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Image Source="xamarin_logo.png"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Shell.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I needed text in the screen header so instead of <Image ...> I used 
<Label Text="My Screen Header" FontSize="30" />